# No module named 'requests_toolbelt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, subprocess

So, I'm trying to upload my python app to heroku but when I use a script with 'requests_toolbelt' it says is not found.

Here my log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "girl.py", line 12, in <module>
    from Coffe import CoffeAPI
  File "/app/CoffeAPI/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
ImportError: No module named 'requests_toolbelt'
```

Here my requeriments.txt:

```
requests-toolbelt==0.7.1
moviepy==0.2.2.11
requests==2.13.0
```

Do I need an specific buildpack to run 'requests_toolbelt'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and my solution was that

> the package was installed by `root` user

and after changing the access properties of the files, it worked fine.
The command I specifically issued (on ubuntu-like system) was:

```
sudo chown $USER.$USER -R ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Answer (score 12):

Try installing requests-toolbelt. Use below command to do that.

```
# pip install requests-toolbelt
```

Comment: I did, it still doesn't exist. Unusual.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to install the package using your command line? 
Navigate your command line to the path where you have python installed:

```
>path\easy_install.exe requests_toolbelt
```

or

```
>path\easy_install.exe requests-toolbelt
```

or

```
>path\python -m pip install requests_toolbelt
```

Hopefully this helps you